# Uninstalled unity and installed lubuntu; now its showing: failed to load session ubuntu; none of the given solutions working

Tags: unity, lubuntu

I uninstalled unity using

```
sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-services unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-applications gir1.2-unity-5.0 unity-common indicator-sound indicator-power indicator-appmenu libindicator7 indicator-application indicator-datetime indicator-messages libnux-2.0-0 nux-tools libunity-misc4 unity-2d-common
```

Then I installed lubuntu using:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

It was a long process and after it finished I shut down the pc. Now when I try to log in to ubuntu, it says failed to load session!
I tried this in `tty1`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install -f install
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

But these didn't work! I guess that happened because of no internet connection but how do I connect to tata photon+ when I am unable to login? If nothing, how can I at least save the files in ubuntu? I have windows XP installed besides ubuntu. Is there a way I can save my files?

Answer (score 1):

You can backup your files simply by using an Ubuntu Live CD or DVD.

1 - Plug in the CD

2 - Boot into live mode

3 - Mount your partitions

4 - Copy your files to an USB drive or something

If your filesystem is extended3 you can download a plugin so Windows Explorer can access your Ubuntu partition-

Or you could use some program like Total Commander with an extendedFS plugin to access your Ubuntu partitions.

For fixing your computer, the best is to do a new LUbuntu installation, by removing Unity you simply removed the most core graphical applications.

And you need an Internet Connection if you want to use apt-get (non-local repositories).

Comment: but i am unable to install anything because i cannot connect to the internet until i login. and my pc is not letting me login.

Comment: You don't need an internet connection to log in into windows

Comment: of course i don't need an internet connection to log into windows. what i am saying is while trying to fix ubuntu i need an internet connection to "do a new LUbuntu installation" which according to you is the best way to fix my computer. And the problem is that to connect to the dongle i use, i need to login!

Comment: You can simply log into windows, download and burn a LUbuntu CD and install it over Ubuntu